# Listen events relative to the @el with backbone.js in the event attribute of a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I write my view like this :

```
class Remobs.Views.Element extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['elements/element']

  events:
    'element_rended': 'initImagesDatas'
    'click img.element_image' : 'observeImageEvents'
    'click .more': 'addToBag'
    'click .less': 'decreaseNumber'

  tagName : 'li'

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(element: @model))
    @currentImage = $(@el).find('img')
    @craftBox = null
    $(@el).trigger('element_rended')
    this
```

And i want to add an element in the events array like this :

```
events:
   'click @el.find('img')' : 'myfunction'
```

Am I able to do that? And how can i do that? I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do `'click @el.find('img')'` but 'click img' is an equivalent of what you want to do - so it's much simpler :)

the way it works is that it takes the first word before first space as a event type and everything after that is turned into a jQuery selector. If you pass just an event name without a selector, event will be bound to `@el` if you pass a selector string it will delegate the event to `@el.find selector_string`

Comment: Thank you, just so simple... Thx for explanation too.

Comment: happy to help and btw - if you are using Backbone 0.9+ you don't need to do `$(@el)` anymore as there is now a jquery wrapped instance of @el available at `@$el`

Comment: Oh... ok, i am just starting using Backbone. Thank you for your advise :) If you can up my post, i will go to the 700 points :)